# Passing multiple variables (image->color-list) as a procedure argument RACKET

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, pseudocode, racket

I am trying to create a procedure which will accept two colour-lists. Because this procedure is within another procedures(local). I need to convert image->color-list as I am passing the arguments.  I have tried different ways to declare them but the compiler error says:

found a variable that is used more than once: image->color-list

or

expected a variable, but found a part

```
 (define (colourLists image->color-list bg image->color-list fg))
 (define (colourLists (image->color-list bg) (image->color-list fg)))
 (define (colourLists (image->color-list bg image->color-list fg)))
```

Is there away to do this or is it something not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I got this right. You have a procedure inside another procedure, that must receive two lists but you have to convert them before passing them. Something like this, perhaps?

```
(define (outerProcedure)
  (define (colourLists color-lst1 color-lst2)
    <inner body>)
  <outer body>
  ; colourLists is called at some point in the outer body
  (colourLists (image->color-list bg) ; bg and fg were defined somewhere else
               (image->color-list fg)))
```

The point is: you'll have to convert the lists before passing them to the inner procedure. Alternatively, you could perform the conversion in the inner procedure:

```
(define (outerProcedure)
  (define (colourLists bg fg)
    (let ((color-lst1 (image->color-list bg))
          (color-lst2 (image->color-list fg)))
    <inner body>))
  <outer body>
  ; colourLists is called at some point in the outer body
  (colourLists bg fg)) ; bg and fg were defined somewhere else
```

Answer (score 2):

"I am trying to create a procedure which will accept two colour-lists."

You don't even need to think too much further yet.  At this point, you know the shape of the function you'll be writing has to fit some form like this:

```
;; some-procedure: (listof color) (listof color) -> ???
(define (some-procedure colour-list-1 colour-list-2)
   <fill-me-in>)
```

That is, deal with the `image->color` list stuff elsewhere.  The function should care only that it gets a list of colors.  Its definition should not care at all whether or not its inputted lists of colors came from a use of `image->color`.